# Microsoft Excel Interop Check whether excel sheet support Autofit

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, office-automation

While working with `Excel Interop`, i come up with an issue. Before Saving I Autofit columns of worksheet with the following code.

```
Excel.Worksheet curSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wsEnumerator.Current;
curSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```

And it works fine for me. Then i encountered an issue with some specific Excel sheet. If i autofit it says `AutoFit method of Range class failed`.

The excel sheet which cause the issue is available [here](http://www.books4school.com/b4s2013.xls)

Now what i want to know is, whether there is some way to check if an excel sheet support Autofit or not. Something like

```
if(sheet.CanAutoFit())
    curSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofit(v=office.11).aspx#Y0 it generates an error if it's not a row or range of rows, or a column or range of columns. Is there something different about the "specific Excel sheet" that would cause this?

Comment: Actually if you open this Excel Document in Microsoft Excel, you will notice, you cant even autofit cells that are available for input. Its some fixed type of excel sheet.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't because your sheet is protected? You can't resize columns on a protected sheet. Once I'd unprotected your example Excel sheet I was able to autofit all of the columns.

Comment: yeah you are right it was protected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no `sheet.CanAutoFit()` then you can always do this:

```
try {
    curSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
} catch (TheSpecificExcelException exc)
{ ... }
```

Comment: But that would not be a good thing to do, to Create exception for something you know will not work. There must be some proper solution for that. And moreover if Mircosoft Excel knows it can not autofit, then there must be some way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was sheet was protected. And to handle that i have used `try` `catch` exception handling. So it has been resolved.